# ngInject and closure compiler

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, google-closure-compiler

I try to compile the following code in ADVANCED mode unsuccessfully:

```
/**
 * @description App configuration
 * @param {!angular.$routeProvider} $routeProvider
 * @constructor
 * @ngInject
 */
function Config ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'mainpage/mainpage.html',
            controller: 'MainpageCtrl'
        })
        .when('/viewer', {
            templateUrl: 'viewer/viewer.html',
            controller: 'ViewerCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}
```

Is there any special flag to be turned on?

If I add the following line it works, but I would like to take advantage of ngInect.

```
Config['$inject'] = ['$routeProvider'];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure compiler needs to run with the "--angular_pass" flag.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', Config]);
```

I am using typescript...