# How do I make angular service injector work with minification?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, angular-services

This angular service works fine with uncompiled javascript. But after google closure compile, it fails on finding the services. Difficult to debug the compiled code.

Can you see what might be wrong?
In file 1:

```
'use strict';
goog.provide('simpleDialogService');

angular.module(‘myApp').service('simpleDialogService', ['$modal',
function ($modal) {
    var dialogDefaults = {};
    dialogDefaults ['templateUrl'] = "partials/dialog.html";


    var dialogOptions = {};
    dialogOptions ['cancelButtonVisibility'] = "hidden";

    var dialogResults = {};

    // other functions, including showDialog()

    this[‘showModalDialog’] = function (customDialogDefaults, customDialogOptions) {
        if (!customDialogDefaults) customDialogDefaults = {};
        customDialogDefaults['backdropClick'] = false;
        return this.showDialog(customDialogDefaults, customDialogOptions);
    };
}]);
```

In file 2:

```
goog.require('extern.jquery');
goog.require('simpleDialogService');
```

Called like this in file2:

```
 function anotherFunction(){
    var promise;
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng', ‘myApp']);
    injector.invoke(['simpleDialogService', function(simpleDialogService){
        promise = simpleDialogService['showModalDialog']({}, dialogOptions);
            }]);
        return promise;
 }
```

or call like this

```
 function anotherFunction2(){
    var promise;
    var injector = angular.injector(['ng', ‘myApp']);
    var myService = theInjector.get('simpleDialogService');
    promise = myService['showModalDialog']({}, dialogOptions);
    return promise;
 }
```

Either form works uncompiled.

Can anyone suggest how to do this in a way that is closure-compile friendly?

Comment: Did you see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345906/nginject-and-closure-compiler

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure if --angular_pass has such wide effect, or only helps with ngInject.  In any event, I did upgrade to latest closure compiler and added --angular_pass. The angular service as written above still works uncompiled, but not compiled.

Comment: It only helps with @ngInject

Comment: @jonR you have a curly quote `‘` instead of an apostrophe `'` in your examples (around myApp), did you also have this in your real code?

Comment: I guess you did, or you'd get a JSC_PARSE_ERROR (cannot edit post so new comment)